# Other ways to factor polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Are there other ways to factor polynomials, some sort of log function or recurrence relation?

I know that the most efficient way is with synthetic or long division, but It would make sense that there are other ways. I don't really care about how fast or well it work I am just curious.

Comment: How do you factor $2x^4-3x^3+x^2-x-2$ “with synthetic or long division”?

Comment: Look up *Diophantine Equation*s by Andreescu, Andrica, Cucurezeanu$$x^3-x^2+y^3-y^2=0 \ \ \ \implies$$ 
$$\left[3(x+y)-2\right]\cdot\left[9(x^2-xy+y^2)-3(x+y)-2\right]=4$$
$$x^2(y-1)+y^2(x-1)=1 \implies (x+y+2)(xy-x-y+2)=5$$